# Omega (hierarchichal) psych package confidence interval

Tags: r, psych

I wondered if there is a way to calculate a reliability confidence interval for omega (hierarchical) using the psych package in R?

I know it can be done with ci.reliability in MBESS but psych is more appropriate for the model I am testing. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Much to my surprise, yes you can find the confidence intervals for omega_h using psych by using the bootstrap.  Just set n.iter=some number. It is faster if you turn off the plotting of the solutions.

```
test10 <- omega(HolzingerSwineford1939[,7:15],n.iter=10,plot=FALSE)

test10
 ...
Estimates and bootstrapped confidence intervals
          lower estimate upper
omega_h   0.086     0.45  0.64
alpha     0.567     0.76  0.80
omega_tot 0.789     0.85  0.87
G6        0.776     0.81  0.84
omega_lim 0.123     0.53  0.82`
```